# stop navigation dots in frankfurt theme - beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using the frankfurt theme in my beamer presentations and i would like to gather 4 slides under the same navigation dot, i.e., do not increment the navigation dot for the 4 frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a new dot, don't start a new frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\subsection{tests}
\begin{frame}
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
slide1
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
slide2
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<3>
slide3
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<4>
slide4
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]